# AGN accretion disk double peak explained?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, astronomy, accretion-disk

I have a question to the following lecture: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Fabian4/Fab2_2.html

[image]

In Figure 3 it says that a narrow annuli of a Newtonian disk should alrdy show a double peak profile. What I don't understand is how the double peak profile formes in the newtonian case? If I imagine a non rotating narrow annuli it has a single peak only at $E_0$. Now when it rotates some photons will be red or blue shifted by the factors $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$, and so on (classical Doppler effect). The rotating narrow annuli is symmetric therefore the number of non shifted photons should be the same as the number of photones shifted by $z_1$ which is the same as number of photons shifted by $z_2$ and so on. So there shouldn't form a double peak profile where the flux of red or blue shifted photones by the factor $z_x$ is bigger than the non shifted photones? But why does a double peak profile according to the lecture form, what do I understand wrong? I would appreciate if someone could walk me trough. 
thx

Comment: That diagram has *two* narrow annuli, as marked by the 2 dashed circles.

Comment: Thats right but it doesn't rly help me because in figure 3 upper panel the two annuli are represented by two different double peak profiles. So one annuli has still a double peak that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what you are missing is that your sightline through the material that is approaching you or receding from you in a nearly edge-on annulus is longer than the sightline through the material that is travelling tangentially to your line of sight.

If the material is optically thin, then the amount of emission you receive will be proportional to the length of the sightline through the material and this is what is responsible for the double peak.

i.e. In the diagram below, the sightline on the right passes through more of the disk material than the sightline in the middle.

[image]